# Webpack uses absolute paths for .node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron

Is there anyway to prevent absolute paths like this when using node_modules that use a .node module? This is what I see when I open the main.bundle.js

```
global.process.dlopen(n,"/Users/<username>/repos/client/node_modules/keytar/build/Release/keytar.node")
```

I would hope that the "keytar.node" module would be copied to the out folder and referenced via relative path.